# Collecting light intensity data while using camera

Tags: android, camera, android-sensors

I am developing an application which collects light intensity in a background service. In this application, the user is allowed to scan a barcode by opening an intent and the camera is displayed. However from the moment, the user opens the intent till he closes it, the light sensor stops collecting data. Is there a way in which I can continue collecting data even while using the camera please?